# How to DRY up this code (if else statement)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dry

What is the best way to make this code more dry? I was thinking of nesting the if-statements where currentRoom.id is the same, or just condense it by adding an || part inside the conditional. But I am not sure if those solutions make the code any neater.

What is the most reasonable and concise style for this kind of thing?

```
if(direction === 'east' && player.currentRoom.id === 1) {
          roomNum = '3';
        } else if (direction ==='east' && player.currentRoom.id === 4) {
          roomNum = '1';
        } else if (direction === 'west' && player.currentRoom.id === 1) {
          roomNum = '4';
        } else if (direction === 'west' && player.currentRoom.id === 3) {
          roomNum = '1';
        } else if (direction === 'north' && player.currentRoom.id === 5) {
          roomNum = '1';
        } else if (direction === 'north' && player.currentRoom.id === 1) {
          roomNum = '2';
        } else if (direction === 'south' && player.currentRoom.id === 1) {
          roomNum = '5';
        } else if (direction === 'south' && player.currentRoom.id === 2) {
          roomNum = '1';
        }
}
```

Comment: What if the room number supposed to be if none of the condition pairs are satisfied?

Comment: Do the rooms have proper euclidean coordinates? Then use a vector for the direction, and just compute the next room by looking it up on a 2d map.

Comment: `roomnum = {
east1:'3',
east4:'1',
west1:'4',
west3:'1',
north5:'1',
north1:'2',
south1:'5',
south2:'1'
}[\`${direction}{$player.currentRoom.id}\`]??0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any other program refactoring, you can compact the repeated syntax in your example by looping over an array of tuples consisting of the variable data in each clause, breaking after the first potential match:

```js
for (const [dir, id, num] of [
  ['east',  1, '3'],
  ['east',  4, '1'],
  ['west',  1, '4'],
  ['west',  3, '1'],
  ['north', 5, '1'],
  ['north', 1, '2'],
  ['south', 1, '5'],
  ['south', 2, '1'],
]) {
  if (direction === dir && player.currentRoom.id === id) {
    roomNum = num;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having an array of arrays for the rooms would mean you'd just have to add/subtract either the current X or Y coordinate. Something like:

```js
const rooms = [
  [0, 2,0],
  [4, 1, 3],
  [0, 5, 0],
];

let horizIndex = 1;
let vertIndex = 1;
console.log(rooms[vertIndex][horizIndex]);

const changeRoom = (x, y) => {
  if (rooms[vertIndex + y][horizIndex + x]) {
    horizIndex = horizIndex + x;
    vertIndex = vertIndex + y;
    console.log('entered', rooms[vertIndex][horizIndex]);
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid room');
  }
};
const direction = 'south';
if (direction === 'south') {
  changeRoom(0, 1);
} else if (direction === 'north') {
  changeRoom(0, -1);
} else if (direction === 'east') {
  changeRoom(1, 0);
} else if (direction === 'west') {
  changeRoom(-1, 0);
}
```